# Parsing Pasted Text with Jquery (no server side processing)

Tags: jquery, forms, paste, fill, onpaste

I need a solution to do the following

User pastes some text into a textarea
User clicks a button "Autofill"
On press of the button, the various lines of the pasted text are put into the     appropriate form fields

```
<p>Copy text into box below to propogate fields</p>
<p>First name: <input data-bind='value: firstName' id='f1'/></p> 
<p>Last name: <input data-bind='value: lastName' id='f2' /></p> 
<p>Postcode:  <input data-bind='value: address' id='f3'/></p>
<h2> <span data-bind='text: fullName'> </span></h2>   
<p>Paste here: <textarea rows="10" cols="30">   </textarea> 
<button><a href="#" onclick="">Autofill</a></button>
```

Here is an example of how the pasted data is formatted.

```
First Name Jimberly  
Last Name Hagg  
Postcode Test
```

My fiddle so far, as you can see there are other things I am testing and in the middle of coding so I hope it's understandable!

http://jsfiddle.net/hc8kL/1/

By the way my jquery to disable the "Continue" button is buggy - it works if you enter some data, but then if you delete it, this isn't noticed by the function and it still keeps the "Continue" button enabled

Comment: The keypress event doesn't catch the backspace, delete, or arrow keys.

Comment: What works? What doesn't? Yes, it's in the middle of development. There are plenty of examples on this website on how to get data from html fields.